# Unclear inequality of L2 norms (Poisson equation for modeling flow)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, functional-inequalities, poissons-equation

I encountered a problem working through a paper about modeling flow with the use of the Poisson equation (source given below). There appears an inequality of L2 norms I don't understand so far. Your help would be greatly appreciated. I try to summarize the setting hereby:

Let there be a convex domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ with two subdomains $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ divided by the 1-dimensional path $\gamma$ (see picture).

[image]

Given the Hilbert spaces
\begin{align}
L &= \{r = (r_1, r_2, r_{\tau}) \in L_2(\Omega_1) \times L_2(\Omega_2) \times L_2(\gamma)\}\\
W &= \{v = (v_1, v_2, v_f) \in H(div,\Omega_1) \times H(div,\Omega_2) \times H(div_\tau,\gamma): v_i \cdot n_i \in L_2(\gamma), i=1,2\}
\end{align}

we let $r = (r_1, r_2, r_{\tau}) \in M$ and $\varphi = (\varphi_1, \varphi_2, \varphi_\gamma) \in H^2(\Omega_1) \times H^2(\Omega_2) \times H^2(\gamma)$ be the solution of the PDE

\begin{align}
-\Delta{\varphi} = \tilde{r} \text{ on } \Omega\\
\varphi = 0 \text{ on } \Gamma
\end{align}
with $\tilde{r} \in L_2(\Omega)$ given by $\tilde{r}\vert_{\Omega_i} = r_i, \ i=1,2$ and
\begin{align}
-\Delta_\tau \varphi_\gamma = r_\tau \text{ on } \gamma\\
\varphi_\gamma = 0 \text{ on } \partial \gamma
\end{align}
We pose
\begin{align}
v_i &= -\nabla \varphi \vert_{\Omega_i}, \ i=1,2\\
v_\gamma &= -\nabla_\tau \varphi_\gamma
\end{align}
so $v=(v_1,v_2,v_\gamma) \in W$ and note that
\begin{align}
\text{div} (v_i) &= r_i, \ i=1,2\\
\text{div}_\tau (v_\gamma) &= r_\tau
\end{align}
$\Delta_\tau$ and $\nabla_\tau$ are the directional Laplacian and gradient along $\gamma$.
Note that $v_1 \cdot n_1 = -v_2 \cdot n_2 \in L_2(\gamma)$ because $v_i \in (H^1(\Omega))^2$.
Furthermore we define the following norms:
\begin{align}
||v||_{0,\Omega_i}^2 = \langle v,v \rangle_{0,\Omega} = \int_{\Omega} v \cdot v \ d\omega\\
||v||_{0,\gamma}^2 = \langle v,v \rangle_{0,\gamma} = \int_{\gamma} v \cdot v \ d \Gamma
\end{align}
with $u \cdot v$ is the dot product.
The proposed inequality is
\begin{multline}
||\tilde{r}||_{0,\Omega}^2 + ||r_\tau||_{0,\gamma}^2 + ||\nabla \varphi||_{0,\Omega}^2 + ||\nabla_\tau \varphi_\gamma||_{0,\gamma}^2 + 2||v_1 \cdot n_1 ||_{0,\gamma}^2\\
\leq (1+C(\Omega))||\tilde{r}||_{0,\Omega}^2+(1+C(\gamma))||r_\tau||_{0,\gamma}^2 + C(\Omega) ||\tilde{r}||_{0,\Omega}^2
\end{multline}
with constants $C(\Omega), C(\gamma) > 0$.

The authorial intention I guessed:

Friedrichs inequality leads to
\begin{align}
||\tilde{r}||_{0,\Omega}^2 + ||\nabla \varphi||_{0,\Omega}^2 \leq (1+C(\Omega))||\tilde{r}||_{0,\Omega}^2\\
||r_\tau||_{0,\gamma}^2 + ||\nabla_\tau \varphi_\gamma||_{0,\Omega}^2 \leq (1+C(\gamma))||r_\tau||_{0,\gamma}^2\\
\end{align}

so it's sufficient to proof
\begin{equation}
2 ||v_1 \cdot n_1||_{0,\gamma}^2 \leq C(\Omega) ||\tilde{r}||_{0,\Omega}^2
\end{equation}
The only way I see to get an inequality of the norms $||\cdot||_{0,\gamma}$ and $||\cdot||_{0,\Omega}$ is Gauss' divergence theorem. Apparently it holds true that:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\gamma} |v_1 \cdot n_1| d\Gamma \leq \sum_{i=1}^2 \int_{\Omega_i} |\text{div} (v_i)| d\omega = \int_{\Omega} |\tilde{r}| d\omega
\end{equation}
because $\gamma \subset \partial \Omega_i,\ i=1,2$.

Unfortunately this is an inequality of $L_1$ norms that does NOT imply the same inequality for $L_2$ norms $||\cdot||_{0,\gamma}$ and $||\cdot||_{0,\Omega}$.

Source (section 4.3, p. 12 [Existence and uniqueness of the solution]):

Jérôme Jaffré, Vincent Martin, Jean Roberts. Modeling Fractures and Barriers as Interfaces for Flow
in Porous Media. [Research Report] RR-4848, INRIA. 2003. 
https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00071735/document